# The intersection and sum of irrelevant ideals are also irrelevant

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, graded-rings

**Definition**: A homogenous ideal $I \subset K[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ is *irrelevant* if $\left <x_0^r,\dots,x_n^r \right> \subset I$ for some $r > 0$.

For $I \cap J$, this is probably circular logic, to argue that $\left <x_0^r,\dots,x_n^r \right> \subset I \cap J \subset I$.

This is to say if $\left <x_0^r,\dots,x_n^r \right> \subset I$ and $\left <x_0^u,\dots,x_n^u \right> \subset J.$

For $I + J$, can one just set the second coordinate to be $0$?

Comment: For the intersection, $r$ night not be the same number for both ideals. You have to find a new $r$ that works for both.

Comment: @MattSamuel, what about the sum?

Comment: The sum is proved essentially the way you attempted to prove it for the intersection.

Comment: How do I use the fact that $I$ and $J$ are irrelevant ot help me...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $I$ and $J$ are irrelevant; then $\langle x_0^r,\dots,x_n^r\rangle\subseteq I$ and $\langle x_0^s,\dots,x_n^s\rangle\subseteq J$ for some $r>0$ and $s>0$.

It's not restrictive to assume $r\le s$ (otherwise just switch the roles of $I$ and $J$). Since $x_i^s\in\langle x_0^r,\dots,x_n^r\rangle$, for $i=0,1,\dots,n$, we have
$$
\langle x_0^s,\dots,x_n^s\rangle\subseteq
\langle x_0^r,\dots,x_n^r\rangle\subseteq I
$$
and so
$$
\langle x_0^s,\dots,x_n^s\rangle\subseteq I\cap J
$$
For the sum it's even easier: any ideal containing an irrelevant ideal is irrelevant as well.

Comment: Wait, why are we alowed to assume $r \leq s$?

Comment: @jacobsmith Given two integers $r$ and $s$, one will be less than or equal to the other. If you don't like this style, just repeat the proof for the case $r>s$, but it's not necessary.

Comment: no that perfectly answers it...